# GUI creator; Graph to custom xml

Tags: c++, c, xml, eclipse, user-interface

I'm looking for a Linux tool or Eclipse plugin for GUI creation.

Background: We're using a c / c++ library for our GUI. The GUI ( Buttons, Labels, List ) is described in simple, but unfortunately custom, XML.

So we need an "Easy to Use graphical object placement" ( Buttons, Strings ) with export function to custom `XML` format.

Is there something I'm looking for?

Comment: Really plain C? Or C++, too?

Comment: language isn't important - c++, too.

Comment: I don't understand the xml part of your question, but you could check QT.

Comment: NoNo, it's easy. I'm using a custom c / c++ lib for GUI creation. The GUI is described in an "custom" xml format. So I need a Graphic-Tool with custom-file-format export.